# Go pprof: Got Error unrecognized profile format

Tags: go, heap-memory, revel, pprof

I'm developing a web program with Go revel framework(my go version is 1.6.2). And I got issues with the memory usage. The memory occupied by revel is increasing almost hundreds of MB every day. So I want to tune the program. Then I learn to use the go pprof and use the revel pprof as said in github.com/revel/modules/tree/master/pprof. But while I'm trying to get the memory profile with following command

> go tool pprof http://sit:9000/debug/pprof/heap.

It got error unrecognized profile format. You can see as following snapshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQKfa.png)
I've struggled on this issue for hours. Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because your debug profile is empty.
You need to specify how often to profile the app using `SetBlockProfileRate`

https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetBlockProfileRate

Just import the `runtime` package in your `main` file and call the `runtime.SetBlockProfileRate` function.

Alternatively, you can use this package, which handles it for you, with some defaults: https://github.com/pkg/profile

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But as I use the revel framework, so the main function will be auto-generated. So I cannot add any codes in the main file. And I can user http://sit:9000/debug/pprof/heap?debug=1 to see the general information. I just cannot use the command to see deeper information.